# Laptop pc vs mac book

Tags: mac

Age old question I know.

So i am going to buy a laptop soon, though cost is an issue. 
I have a mac at work and love it. But i need something for home to do extra projects or work late on.

I feel like I could use a pc laptop as I hear that they are just as good power-wise as a macbook, but is there any issues with this that im not aware of?

Will my files from work also be compatable with the pc laptop at home?
(I use adobe suite as per and Sketch etc)

Is PC more likely to crash (this is something I heard at work – but as I dont intend to use if for downloaded movies etc and only use it for work i am not expecting to get software that clashes)

Does anyone know what pc brands I should start looking at? or if i should start looking at 2nd hand mac books?

Thanks all!

Comment: This is *entirely* based upon user preference. All the answers you get will be biased towards *that user's preference* and may not be accurate for *your* usage or preferences unless you happen to do the *exact* same work at the *exact* same level as someone who answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Sketch for windows, if thats a dealbreaker for you then the discussion is over.

The thing is that you get what you pay for, if you buy the cheapest pc available then indeed it will be quite terrible, dont do it. Even more important is getting the right graphics card. But a higher end pc running windows is just as stable as a mac on most loads (in some cases stabler)

But really the annoying thing about this is mixin and matching as the keyboard layouts are quote different. I dont generally mind swapping software with different keybindings but jumping between mac and pc causes a lot of missclicks the first year.

Comment: Thanks... Using Sketch is about 30% of my work. I can do without it but that coupled with getting uesd to the new keyboard etc might just be too much to bear.

Answer (score 0):

The two platforms are very close in terms of performance and stability, so the cost savings of a PC may seem appealing. However, if you aren't already comfortable with Windows, the differences may cause frustration that outweighs the cost benefit - especially if your time on that computer is intended to be for profit. Unless you're going to use it with enough regularity to get up to speed (and stay up to speed) on the Window-way of system operation, I would recommend sticking to Mac OS. On the other hand, if you're just curious about Windows and would like to test it out for the adventure of it, then you can always run a Windows virtual machine on the Mac. (This is coming from a PC user.)